# How do I change the color of md-tab-header?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

Is there a way to change the color of `md-tab`'s header to yellow?

I tried the following code but it does not work:

```css
.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-ripple {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Does anyone has this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cannot fix this way.. you need to create a theme for it

Comment: If you use the ngc compiler or cli you can use shadow-piercing or `/deep/ .md-blah { `

Comment: When i try to edit it using the console and change the DOM elements value we are able to change to color which means obviously their is some way to change the color @ara

Answer (score 1):

Add in the following code to your `css` file:

```css
.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-ripple {
   background-color: red !important;
}
```

It worked for me!

Comment: Add this code in your static css file imported in src/index.html in your main project, to forced css. This answer has edited :(